# To Find set of lines intersecting at a given point CGAL

Tags: cgal

In newer version of CGAL, given a set of line segments, we can't find out the set of lines interesting at a point. I am checking them pairwise using do_intersect() but it's very slow. Can someone suggest me a better way?

My goal is to to find out all pairs of intersecting segments in a give set of line segments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the package [Intersecting Sequences of dD Iso-oriented Boxes](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Box_intersection_d/index.html) which will reduce your intersection test to segments having there bbox intersecting.
See also this [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Box_intersection_d/Box_intersection_d_2minimal_8cpp-example.html).